# String pattern Regular Expression python

Tags: python, regex

I am a novice in regular expressions. I have written the following regex to find `abababab9` in the given string. The regular expression returns two results, however I was expecting one result.

```
testing= re.findall(r'((ab)*[0-9])',temp);


**Output**: [('abababab9', 'ab')]
```

According to my understanding, it should have returned only `abababab9`, why has it returned `ab` **alone**.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to say "it should have returned only `abababab9`"? (there's one more `ba` in your code)

Comment: alone you mean along? regular expression takes every () as a group, the whole expression is group 0. You can use ?: to ignore the group you dont want, i mean (ab)

Answer (score 2):

You didnt' read the `findall` documentation:

> Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.
>
> **If one or more capturing groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups;** this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has
>   more than one group.
>
> Empty matches are included in the result.

And if you take a look at the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module capturing groups are subpatterns enclosed in parenthesis like `(ab)`.

If you want to only get the complete match you can use one of the following solutions:

```
re.findall(r'(?:ab)*[0-9]', temp)  # use non-capturing groups

[groups[0] for groups in re.findall(r'(ab)*[0-9]', temp)] # take the first group

[match.group() for match in re.finditer(r'(ab)*[0-9]', temp)] # use finditer
```

Answer (score 1):

You have configured by `(...)` two matching groups the **first group** is `((ab)*[0-9])` and the **second group** is `(ab)`. Therefore you get these two results. To get only the first group you could make the second a **non-capturing group**. This is done by `?:`. So this result is not delivered.

```
((?:ab)*[0-9])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4bkDIaHhdlU9Rd4y)

This one only matches `abababab9`.

**Edit 1:**

Here is an explanation of the grouping concept of regular expressions: [groups and capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: what is meant by `capturing group`?

Comment: Capturing group is a part of the regular expression that is delivered to you. That does not has to be the complete expression, like in your case it could be a subset or subsets of it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second group capturing `(ab)` using `?:` inside:

```
testing= re.findall(r'((?:ab)*[0-9])',temp);
```

Comment: What do you mean by group?

Comment: Anything you use inside `()` is captured inside a group from the regex matching. In your regex it had two `()`.

Comment: When is the right time to use () parrenthesis & when should one use (?:)?

Comment: If you do not need to catch the group from matching then use `?:`. Please check this [python doc](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping).